# wget fails to perform in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, wget

I want to iterate through a list of url's (linking to pictures) and perform a `wget` to download those pictures.

But the url's are between quotation marks.
I initially put a `$` sign in front of the picture variables. It works in a colab notebook, I can actually download the pictures this way in my notebook, but it does not work when I launch the script via my Windows command.

```
for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.get_followers, screen_name='@'+screen_name, wait_on_rate_limit=True, count=200).items(9000):
  followers_profile_pic.append(follower.profile_image_url_https)
  for pic in followers_profile_pic:
    pic_id = re.search(pattern, pic).group(1)
    big_pic = f"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/{pic_id}_400x400.jpg"

  quality_pic.append(big_pic)
  for picture in quality_pic:
    wget picture
```

Comment: Did you get any error message? If yes please provide it, if not describe what does actually happen more precisely than *does not work*

Comment: `wget picture` is not correct Python syntax. Do you mean `wget(picture)`? Or do you think that you can use Bash commands and Bash syntax in Python?

Answer (score 0):

> can actually download the pictures this way in my notebook, but it
> does not work when I launch the script via my Windows command.

If portability is concern to you then it is wise to limit to standard library if feasible. There is function specially designed for downloading files - namely [`urllib.request.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html). Most basic usage is to provide URL and filename, for example:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.example.com","index.html")
```

`urllib.request` is part of standard library so generally it should be sufficent to have `python` installed, unlike external modules, e.g. `requests` which need separate installation. If you want to know more about `urllib.request.urlretrieve` read linked docs.